# How to convert array 2D to 1D in C++

Tags: c++

I have 2D array arr[i][j]. Where i is the index of list while [j]= list of five elements. For example

```
arr[0][1,2,3,4,5]  
arr[1][6,7,9,2,1] 
...
arr[n][1,3,2,4,8]
```

I want to convert it into 1D so that index indicator get remove and have list of elements only. Please guide me.

Comment: The mechanics for doing this can vary widely, depending on the actual type of `arr` and the actual type of the resulting expected sequence container, neither of which are included in your question. Please [update the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71935149/edit) to *real code* conveying that information.

Comment: it is unclear what you mean when you write `arr[0][1,2,3,4,5]` because thats not valid C++ syntax. Do you mean elements of `arr[0]` are `1,2,3,4,5` ?

Comment: Rather than making up some squirrelly syntax to provide an "example", try describing what you mean.   Assume a *human* needs to understand your description, as distinct from "a human who understands your squirrelly notation even if you haven't described it".   Because most people do not understand a squirrelly notation that someone else has made up without a description of what that notation means.

Answer (score 1):

a more modern and working solution could be something like this.

```
std::array<std::array<int,4>,3> ar;
ar[0]={2,3,4,5};
ar[1]={6,7,8,9};
ar[2]={10,11,12,13};

std::vector<int> oneD;
for(const auto& firstLayer : ar){
    for(const auto& secondLayerItem: firstLayer){
       oneD.push_back(secondLayerItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `std::span` to create a 1D view over the 2D array:

```cpp
std::span sp(std::data(arr[0]), std::size(arr) * std::size(arr[0]));
```

Or simpler:

```cpp
std::span sp(*arr, std::size(arr) * std::size(*arr));
```

Or if you already have the dimensions of the original array:

```cpp
std::span sp(*arr, i * j);
```

Now you can view elements in `sp` with `sp[N]`. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ebeaEd6xn

---

Note, `span` is only a view over the original array, so any modifications on `sp`'s element will be reflected to the original array.

Comment: Note: this is only working from C++20, for something that works in previous versions, see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through your 2d array and push into a new 1d array

```
vector<vector<int>> twoD;
vector<int> oneD;
for (int i=0; i<twoD.size(); i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<twoD[i].size(); j++) {
    oneD.push_back(twoD[i][j]);
  }
}

return oneD;
```